# How to get pool.py to accept non ascii characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python 2.7.18
The idea is to use python to gather songs from specified directories, then create and run the commands to run them through a bunch of converters and sound processors.
Some of my songs have characters with accents and any song with a ? in the title gets changed to a ¿ (Inverted Question Mark) in the file name.

My convert_song function works correctly when ran, but when I try to run it in a Pool and the file name or directory has a non ascii character in it, it fails with:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\StreamLine.py", line 270, in <module>
    result = pool.map(convert_song, qTheStack)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 253, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 572, in get
    raise self._value
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's my main where I set up the pool:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Reading artists.')
    predir = 'G:\\Vault\\The Music\\'
    artistfile = open('C:\\Controls\\ArtistList.txt', 'r')
    artistlist = artistfile.readlines()
    dirs = []
    for artist in artistlist:
        dirs.append(predir + artist.strip())
    qTheStack = []
    for currentPath in dirs:
        for wFile in generate_next_file(currentPath):
            print(repr(wFile))
            #print(convert_song(wFile))
            qTheStack.append(wFile)
    print('List loaded.')
    pool = Pool(12)
    result = pool.map(convert_song, qTheStack)
    for item in result:
        print(item)
```

The print(repr(wFile)) looks like this when ran:

```
'G:\\Vault\\The Music\\Chicago\\1989 - Greatest Hits 1982-1989\\04 - Will You Still Love Me\xbf.flac'
'G:\\Vault\\The Music\\Chicago\\1989 - Greatest Hits 1982-1989\\06 - What Kind of Man Would I Be\xbf [Remix].flac'
```

How can I get the built-in Pool from multiprocessing to accept my input?

Comment: I think you should upgrade to Python 3. Python 2.7 is obsolete and out of support since long time. In addition it has a very different way to handle character encoding, so you may need to learn two very different ways of handle it. Personally: I do not remember exactly how i did long ago, and I do not have python 2 installed to test, so I'll not answer. I think many of us are in the same situation.

Comment: I suppose I knew the first suggestion was going to be change to Python 3.
They have had time to make it potentially better.

Comment: Python 3 completely changed the strings and how we see them (so much chaos at beginning), but now all encoding stuffs seems much more natural. It just changed the way of thinking, on the very topic of your question. We may be able to answer on general topic about python 2.7, but strings were always tricky. Note (and you will hit this problem). Also in Python3, Windows is the only operating system without UTF-8 as default system encoding (it seems to change in near future, on windows side, so beware),

Comment: I'm on Windows 11 so maybe that's already in place for me? Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to Python 3, dude.

As much as I wanted there to be an answer that stayed on Python 2.7, I tried Python 3 and it didn't disappoint.
I did have to go back through the [obscure steps](https://www.codementor.io/@spyoungtech/how-to-use-dlls-com-objects-from-python-or-how-to-send-a-fax-with-python-192lmtt5p5) I found to generate a file that will run a COM/DLL in Python, and I had to remove all the str.decode and encode calls throughout my script. After only one import change, I hit run and it ran as expected.